# Why is there an extra folder added when cloned from github to sublime text?

Tags: python, github, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have just started using github, why does my github repository look like this (1st) but my sublime text has an extra folder (avg-daily-balance) after I've cloned it into sublime? (2nd)

github file structure:

[image]

sublime text file structure:

[image: sublime text file structure]

Comment: It looks like you gave the wrong root folder to Sublime Text.

Comment: Because `git clone` always clones into a new folder.